# Heat equation 2D with a cold path

Tags: python, 2d, heat

I'm currently facing an issue in order to resolve an heat equation in 2 dimensions with a cold path at the center of a square which represents my metal piece.
Indeed, even if i have the heat equation (conduction) and i know how to numericaly solve it, i don't know how to keep the cold path at the same temperature (which is my boundary condition) and make the cold spread in all directions.
What i am looking for is this :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6XPn.jpg)

but with a cold path at the center which spread by time, following my heat equation.
Does someone have any idea to solve this issue ?
Have a nice day,

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to ask questions about concrete problems involving programming. Are you stuck somewhere with code? If so, what have you tried so far?

If it is not related to coding, it might be better suited for stack exchange sites like [Matter Modelling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) or [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) (you may want to read up on their rules first to see if your question fits).

Comment: Can you write the equation that defines the system as a ODE or an SDE, one could use this to provide you with the simulation.

Comment: @jrbergen It does

Comment: @user4933 Yes here it is : https://www.zupimages.net/up/21/21/gg89.png

Comment: D represents the thermal diffusivity

Comment: Could you simplify your system into 2D, I don't think one can see what you mean by the partial derivative of T both with respect to x and y. You'd need an explicit expression.